# ¿Como manejar roles al iniciar session en php y mysql?

Tags: php, sql

Hola buenas tardes estoy intentando que al iniciar session un usuario lo redireccione segun el roll al cual esta asociado dentro de la tabla,en este caso hay dos tipos el roll admin y el roll limitado quiero saber como podria lograr esto lo que tengo hasta ahora es lo siguiente:, que basicamente es solo el login sin condicion de roles.

```
    <?php session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){

    header('Location: index.php');

}


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $usuario = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['usuario']),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password = hash('sha512', $password);
    $errores ='';   
    try{
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=centromedico','root','');
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Error: ". $e->getMessage();
    }
    $statement = $conexion -> prepare(
            'SELECT * FROM usuarios');

    $statement ->execute(array(':usuario'=> $usuario,':password'=> $password ));

    $resultado = $statement->fetch();
    if($resultado !==false){
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        header('Location: index.php');
    }else{
        $errores .= 'Datos incorrectos y/o invalidos!';
    }
}
    require 'vista/login.php';
?>


Y este es el index.php donde se redirige al menu.

    <?php session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    header('Location: CenterMedicine.php');
}else{
    header('Location: login.php');
}   
?>
```

Comment: ¿La consulta funciona así como la tienes?

Comment: En mi caso lo que te recomendaría si te interesa tener un mayor control tanto de roles como permisos y por ende permitir la creación de nuevos roles, es que utilices el patrón RBAC (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) ó https://hitachi-id.com/documents/role-based-access-control-explained-and-implemented.php?page=2

Answer (score 1):

Un switch case te daría la posibilidad de un default location y poder agregar otros según el rol

```
<?php 

   session_start();
   $location = 'Location: login.php';

   if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
      switch ($_SESSION['usuario']['rol']) {
        case 'admin':
           $location = 'Location: indexAdmin.php';
           break;
        case 'usuario':
           $location = 'Location: indexUsuario.php';
           break;
        case 'dotor':
           $location = 'Location: indexMedico.php';
           break;
        default:
           $location = 'Location: indexGenerico.php';
       }
   }

   header($location);
?>
```

Comment: Lo intente con el sw case pero me tira error lo deje asi:<?php 

   session_start();
   $location = 'Location: login.php';

   if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
      switch ($_SESSION['usuario']['Roll']) {
        case 'admin':
           $location = 'Location: CenterMedicine.php';
           break;
        case 'Limitado':
           $location = 'Location: index2.php';
           break;    
       }
   }

   header($location);
?>

Comment: es un ejemplo de implementación, yo personalmente iría por cargar diferentes partes (require_once) en un mismo index.php según el rol. o si cambia demasiado el UI asignarles carpetas (reales o virtuales) `admin/index.php` etc..